# Remove mode entirely

Tags: python

I am trying to write a method that removes the mode entirely from a list. I've looked up other articles to use a for loop but it doesn't entirely get rid of the mode from the list like it needs to.

this is what my list would look like before I get rid of the mode entirely from a list.
`list = 1,3,4,6,3,1,3,`
I have already tried the .remove function but it only removes 1 of the numbers
my expected outcome
`list = 1,4,6,1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mylist.remove(x)` removes only the *first* occurrence of x from the list.

If you think there may be more than one, use a while loop:

```
while 3 in mylist:
    mylist.remove(3)
```

If the list is long and/or there might be several 3s in the list, this approach would be more efficient, as it only iterates over the list once:

```
mylist = [item for item in mylist if item != 3]
```